# Is there a Python library that can generate charts within Excel?

Tags: python, excel

I know python can manipulate Excel data but I don't know whether it can generate charts in it.

Does such a library exist?

Comment: Where have you looked? What have you tried?

Comment: @MikeWoodhouse I looked a python package named xlrd and xlwt, but it seems that it can not generate charts.

Answer (score 2):

Excel is an [OLE Automation server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLE_Automation) (which is built on [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model)), which means it has a discoverable interface that makes it possible to automate it from any tool that understands COM. Providing you're on Windows, Python is one of many such tools and you already have (or can easily obtain) the library you need: it's PythonCom.

See [this snippet](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2036) for an example of how a Python script uses the library to talk to Excel. It doesn't seem to explicitly work with charts, so you'll need to figure that out for yourself: try using the Macro Recorder to get an idea (in VBA) of how to achieve what you want, then translate that into Python.

If you're not running on Windows, then you're going to need code that understands the Excel file format, which is fairly achievable in the new xlsx/xlsm XML-based world (available from Excel 2007 onwards) and rather more difficult in the old binary xls form.